# Entity Framework Core, discard and update a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-core

I have a Winforms test application that I'm using to try to learn about Entity Framework Core.

I have a datagridview bound to my table and I can edit fields and call `context.SaveChanges()` - works fine.

What if I have edited several cells on different rows, deleted and added a row, then changed my mind and I don't want to save?  How can I discard the changes and refresh the datagridview with the original data?

I call `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Load(context.entity)` and then `dataGridView1.Refresh()` but my form remains unchanged with my changes.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = context.enity.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To load data from database you have to instantiate the Context again:

```
context = new SampleDbContext(options);
```

then you can reload your grid any way that's possible. I think the easiest possible way is to assign it again:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = context.MyDbSet;
```

And one more thing (just in case you want to learn more); EF is not designed to be used with long lived contexts. The best way to use EF is to dispose the DbContext instance after you are done with it:

```
using(var ctx = new SampleDbContext()){
    instances = ctx.MyDbSet....
}
```

Comment: In the help on page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/efcore-and-ef6/choosing it suggests using Entity Framework Core for new applications and in the feature comparison on page  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features it says it supports Winforms.  Reading that documentation I was steered away from EF6; have I miss-understood?

Comment: You are absolutely right! I didn't know that, I'm so sorry for the wrong information Alec! I even did a sample with EFCore in a WinForm project and it worked just fine! I edited my post.